# how do i open ALL the excel files one by one and run a macro

Tags: vba, file-io

I need to write a macro in VBA that will open every file in a given directory one by one and run a macro on them.

so far i have something like

```
for i = 1 to number_of_files
    open Dir("C:\yourPath\*.*", vbNormal)
    call some_macro
    close file
next i
```

Comment: Have you started? What code do you have so far? Does the macro reside in each workbook, or are you trying to execute a macro in one workbook against others?

Comment: the macro is only in the ONE workbook

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By calling the `Dir()` function with an appropriate filter, such as `"c:\folder\*.xls"`, you start enumeration and get the first file name.
After that, repeatedly calling the `Dir()` function without any parameters, you will get all `*.xls` file names, one for each call.

You open a workbook by calling `Workbooks.Open(full_path)`. This gives you a `Workbook` object, against which you can run a macro.

The `.Close()` method of this `Workbook` object closes the workbook. You can use `.Close(SaveChanges:=True)` to save changes, `.Close(SaveChanges:=False)` to discard changes, or omit the parameter to have the user decide.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy VBA object way to do it:

```
Dim fs As FileSearch
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set fs = Application.FileSearch

With fs
    .LookIn = ThisWorkbook.Path
    .FileName = "*.xls"
    For i = 1 to .Execute()
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(.FoundFiles(i))
        ''//RUN MACRO HERE
        wbk.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    Next i
End With
```