# Counting words in each document in a directory

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have come across many word counting macros for VBA but i cant figure out how i can iterate over each "doc" file in a directory and generate a report of number of words in each file. How can we generate such a report?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3375175/11683 to get started.

Comment: thanks  but answers are not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What GSerg was getting at is that you need to iterate through the folder containing the documents, open them, and get the word counts.

As far as I know you can't get the word counts without opening the documents (through VBA that is) without installing an additional library, as described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351/en-us

However I wouldn't do that anyway, since the counts in the file properties are, in my experience, inaccurate as I believe that they use the Words property which has the issue described in this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291447

Accordingly if you want to get the accurate counts, I believe that the only way is to loop through the files and open them, like so. Remember to change the path name to your real one:

```
Sub ListWordCount()
    'In the Visual Basic Editor,
    'go to Tools -> References and check the box for
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime to access the
    'filesystem object.

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fol As Scripting.Folder
    Dim cfil As Variant
    Dim fil_1 As Scripting.File

    Dim s As String

    'The FSO isn't the fastest object in existence
    'and much slower than using the Windows API (or its
    'VB.Net namesake for that matter) but it's convenient
    'and easy to use.
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fol = fso.GetFolder("InsertYourPathHere")
    Set cfil = fol.Files

    'Helps it run a bit faster...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each fil_1 In cfil

        Select Case fil_1.Type
            'Add any other types that you want to check for
            Case "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document", _
             "Microsoft Word Document"

            Documents.Open FileName:=fil_1.Path

            Debug.Print fil_1.Name & vbTab & _
             ActiveDocument.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) _
             & " words."

            Documents.Close savechanges:=False

        End Select

    Next

ExitPoint:
On Error Resume Next
Set fil_1 = Nothing
Set cfil = Nothing
Set fol = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenRefresh
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description

Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Comment: excellent answer ! indeed very valuable for many auditing scripts for documents. I could save n$ for an accurate word count!