# Several file selection using vb for excel if part of file basename is same

Tags: file, excel, selection, vba

I am facing a typical problem wherein I have to select files containing same basename (part of it) and different extentions like pdf, xls, idf, etc.
I can do it using filedialog which allows manual selection, but i have to repeat the operation several times and it is extremely cumbersome process. So I am looking forward to do it using vb excel iteratively.

Presently, I tokk help from some colleague who did it using linux programming, which I do not like.

I have to subsequently do some operations on them like renaming, moving, etc. I am able perform these tasks successfully.

Comment: Set multiselect=true on the file dialog, and provide a file filter with [several extensions in one entry](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/HV080550423.aspx).

Comment: Hi GSerg,I have mentioned above that I am aware of filedialog option where i can select files manually. I am looking forward to a code which can select files having part of basename same.

Comment: Question is tagged `vb.net`.  Is it actually `vb.net` or is it `vba`? And is base name user specified or code specified?

Comment: Chris, Appologies. It is vba. The part of basename has a logic. First 12 charaters will be always same (for say three files ) and same is true for other files. These 12 characters are available in a excel workbook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i open ALL the excel files one by one and run a macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375175/how-do-i-open-all-the-excel-files-one-by-one-and-run-a-macro)

Comment: GSerg, I disagree. I do not want to open any file since these are not excel compatible. I have to only select all files meeting some logic (part of basename should be same as a string from excel workbook), then I want to zip them.

Comment: Take the code from my answer. Replace the call to `Workbooks.Open(full_path)` with a call to `Zip(full_path)`.

Comment: The function `Dir` in a loop will return, one at a time, the names of files matching a pattern.  Search for "Excel VBA Dir" and you will find many web sites showing you how to use this function.  Is this the first part of what you seek?

Comment: Tony, You are correct. I am looking for several file selection based on a pattern.

Comment: Note, this is your questions so you will be told if anyone posts a comment or answer against.  If you had included "@TonyDallimore" or "@chris neilson" in your comment, we would have been told you had replied to our comments.

Answer (score 1):

This macro demonstrates different uses of the `Dir` function:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DemoDir()

  Dim FileName As String
  Dim PathName As String

  ' This gets the path of the active workbook. I find it convenient
  ' with this type of task, to place the workbook containing the macro
  ' in the folder holding the files I want to examine.  Alternatively,
  ' you can set PathName to any folder you can reach.
  PathName = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  ' This locates each file in PathName with a name starting with "Token"
  ' and an extension of "txt".  It output the name of each file located to
  ' the Immediate Window.  This is an easy way to check you are finding
  ' the correct files.
  FileName = Dir$(PathName & "\Token*.txt")
  Do While FileName <> ""
    Debug.Print FileName
    FileName = Dir$
  Loop

  Debug.Print "-------------------------------"

  ' This locates each file in PathName with a name starting with "T"
  ' and any extension.
  FileName = Dir$(PathName & "\T*.*")
  Do While FileName <> ""
    Debug.Print FileName
    FileName = Dir$
  Loop

  Debug.Print "-------------------------------"

  ' This locates each file in PathName with a name starting with "Te"
  ' and whose fourth character is "t" and whose extension starts with "x".
  FileName = Dir$(PathName & "\Te?t*.x*")
  Do While FileName <> ""
    Debug.Print FileName
    FileName = Dir$
  Loop

End Sub
```

The above macro merely lists file names to the Immediate Window.  If you want to rename or move files you need to use the `Name` statement.  I find the name `Name` confusing and unhelpful but it does what you want.  Its syntax is:

**Name** *oldpathname* **As** *newpathname*

Look up the `Name` statement in the VB Editor's Help for more information.